# What transformation should be carried out if the count is non-integer in poisson glm in r?

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, count-data

My data is like this:

```
person   final   sex
1        34.20    1
2        2.00     0
3        15.58    0
4        18.00    1
5        50.06    1
```

I am fitting `po = glm (final ~ sex, data=df, family="poisson")`, there are warnings because "final" is not a integer. Final is a count of risky behaviours. What can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: What does it mean when the count of risky behaviors is non-integer, such as 34.2?

Comment: No transformation. Either your data are suitable as they come, or you should use a different method.

Comment: When *I* count things I only get integers; if I get non-integer values like 50.06 I did something other than just *counting*. Can you explain how it happens that none of your counts are integers? Are they averages of counts, for example? Are they rates per unit time? Why would you choose to model what are clearly *not counts* as Poisson? The manner in which these non-integral values arise will be important to suitable approaches to the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When performing Poisson regression, it is assumed that the response variable (in your case, `final`) is an integer, as the goal of Poisson regression is to model count data.  In this case, a transformation would not be the appropriate solution-- my suggestion is to check how you arrived at the values for `final`. If `final` represents counts of risky behaviors it should be composed of all integers.

Comment: Say rather that many implementations assume and enforce this. Others are happy to be more generous. The fact the the normal is a limiting case of the Poisson is one illustration of the idea that it's often not outrageous to regard the Poisson as approximately continuous. Similarly in data analysis many implementations are broader-minded and to good effect. See e.g. http://blog.stata.com/2011/08/22/use-poisson-rather-than-regress-tell-a-friend/ and its references. Arguably, being Poisson even conditionally is no more central to Poisson regression than being Gaussian is to linear regression.

Comment: @Nick You're correct--I've read and appreciated that blog post before. I sympathize with Ben F's answer here, though (+1), because he rightly points out that those warning messages raise a huge flag: although (in the hands of an expert who will know enough to anticipate and ignore such warnings) Poisson regression with non-integral data can be meaningful, very likely what it indicates is the wrong procedure has been selected or that the data have been incorrectly coded.

Comment: @whuber Agreed. The detailed questions about the OP's data remain and the widespread usefulness of Poisson regression does not imply that it is a good choice for his data.